# Is there any tool for code size analysis that works on both *.elf and *.axf?

Tags: c, arm, elf

I'm using gcc and armclang (arm compiler 6) in order to compile (and link) few libraries into one executable file (elf/axf).
Is there any tool for code size analysis that works on both files?
The problems are:

1. The map files shows the data in a different way, and I need one solution for both files (elf/axf)
2. I need to preset the data by files and functions, but I also need to distinguish between the libraries
3. This is preferred, but not a must - I want to be able to compare between old and new versions of the executable files

I'm familiar with "size -t", "arm-none-eabi-size", "arm-none-eabi-nm", and aware to the fact that the data is located in some way in the map file, but none of these options give me what I need.

Are there any options for "size" that I can use?
Are there any linkers options that might answer my needs?

Does anyone familiar with the puncover tool? (https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/best-firmware-size-tools)
Does it work on *.axf as well? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cross-binutils for `arm-none-elf` (or another 32-bit Arm target), then its `size` program should work with both ELF and `.axf` files (which are just ELF files with a different file extension).